# How do I delete all directories with a certain file type in them?

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, files, directory

I'm writing a command line script to 'unpack' folders with `.svg` files from downloads. I've copied the required files to a specific directory and now I need to delete all the **directories with `.svg` files in them** because they are full of other formats and licences, which I don't need. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

GNUly, that could be:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.svg' -type f -printf '%h\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -rf
```

Where `find` reports the dirname of all `.svg` *regular* files, `sort -zu` removes duplicates, and `xargs rm` removes them.

That's not terribly efficient in that it keeps looking for `.svg` files in children of a given directory even after `.svg` file have been found in it.

Note that if the current directory contains `.svg` files, `rm` will refuse to delete it (as a safeguard on `rm -rf .` to work around a misfeature in some shells where `rm -rf .*` includes `.` and `..` in the expansion of `.*`).

You can work around that by replacing `.` with `"$PWD"` above.

Remove the `echo` when you're satisfied it will do what you want.

With the [`bosh` shell](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html), you could do it more efficiently  with its builtin `find`:

```
has_svg() {
  find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.svg' -type f -call return 0 \;
  return 1
}

find . -type d -call 'has_svg "$1"' {} \; -prune -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the `find` command before, but I probably did something wrong earlier. It seems to be one of the slightly more confusing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU find we employ find within find to first look at a dir starting from the lower levels and then check whether that dir comprises atleast one .svg file. We delete such dirs.

```
$ find . -depth  ! -name . -type d  \
    -exec sh -c '
      N=$#
      for d do
        test "x$(find "$d/." -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.svg" -print -quit)" != "x" &&
          set -- "$@" "$d"
      done
      shift "$N"; rm -rf ${1+"$@"}
 ' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: Fixed the issue. Thanks.